# imaplib.IMAP4.error: FETCH command error: BAD [b'Command Error. 10']

Tags: python, imap, imapclient, pyzmail

I get an error when trying to fetch emails from sent items while it works perfectly when I fetch emails from INBOX.
Anyone has the same issue?

thank you all.

```
import imapclient, pprint , pyzmail ,re
import socket

out = {}



socket.getaddrinfo('127.0.0.1', 8080)

imapObj = imapclient.IMAPClient('outlook.office365.com', ssl=True) # Access IMAP server

imapObj.login('email', 'pass') # Credintial logins

imapObj.select_folder('Sent Items', readonly=False) # Select inbox folder in IMAP server to search

#pprint.pprint(imapObj.list_folders())

UIDs = imapObj.search(['ALL']) # search from email to reutrn IDs

for i in UIDs:
    

    data = imapObj.fetch(UIDs, ['BODY[]']) #UIDs to the fetch() method to obtain the email content

    message = pyzmail.PyzMessage.factory(data[i][b'BODY[]'])
    
    header = str(message.get_subject())
    
    print(header)
```

Error and traceback as below :

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\alaziza\Desktop\Python\sentCCverification.py", line 24, in 
data = imapObj.fetch(UIDs, 'RFC822').items() #UIDs to the fetch() method to obtain the email content
File "C:\Users\alaziza\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\imapclient\imapclient.py", line 1367, in fetch
typ, data = self._imap._command_complete("FETCH", tag)
File "C:\Users\alaziza\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\imaplib.py", line 1027, in _command_complete
raise self.error('%s command error: %s %s' % (name, typ, data))
imaplib.IMAP4.error: FETCH command error: BAD [b'Command Error. 10']

Comment: Please fix your code formatting, and provide the _full_ traceback, specifically showing which line number it hits. You should paste in your code, highlight it all, then press {} in the editor which should indent it all for and make it one nice code block.

Comment: I have formatted the code for a better viewing.

Comment: We still need the _full_ error and traceback.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\alaziza\Desktop\Python\sentCCverification.py", line 24, in <module>
    data = imapObj.fetch(UIDs, ['BODY[]']) #UIDs to the fetch() method to obtain the email content
  File "C:\Users\alaziza\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\imapclient\imapclient.py", line 1367, in fetch
    typ, data = self._imap._command_complete("FETCH", tag)

Comment: File "C:\Users\alaziza\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\imaplib.py", line 1027, in _command_complete
    raise self.error('%s command error: %s %s' % (name, typ, data))
imaplib.IMAP4.error: FETCH command error: BAD [b'Command Error. 10'] this is the error

Comment: Thanks, it would be more helpful edited into your question (formatted as code as well).  Cheers!

Comment: A note about your code: you're looping in UIDs, but sending all UIDs, not `i` on each fetch, meaning you're attempting to fetch all the UIDs, UIDs times.  Your problem might just be you need fetch(i), and to read the one response.

Comment: yes worked , thank you so much Max, what confused me it worked perfectly with INBOX uids list while gave me this error when switched to sent items. :)